# What is the impact of multiple cookies in my asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies, global-variables, session-cookies

I have an vb.net website, but I cant seem to declare global variables, so what impact will it have on both client and server side if i create cookies for my global variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first investigate why you can not have global variables.

In ASP.NEt you can not "declare" global variables but instead you need to add them

to session object or Application objects:

```
Session("MyVariable")=12
```

And later you can easily read it as:

```
Dim b as integer=Session("MyVariable")
```

Cookies are always created on client machine and they are not proper way for storing the all of the global variables but mainly user preferences.

Impact is client browser may not allow cookies and then your program will fail at storing it. Also cookies safety is debatable.